# How to get the X and Y of a zoom canvas p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm having a trouble getting the X and Y of a canvas. So originally this is my canvas.

[image]

And I'm using a **scale()** to zoom my canvas, and when I use it, it will become like this.

[image]

My goal is to get the X and Y of this part of my zoomed canvas

[image]

I tried to get the the width and height of my canvas, however I can't show the object that I locate to the zoomed canvas. I need to zoom it out just to show it. I want to get the x and y of that part of my canvas so even I zoom in or zoom out the canvas, it will stay there. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: how exactly are you using lerp to zoom?

Comment: @MasterYushi I updated the question, I used **scale()** to zoom and used **lerp()** to make it smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is just `width/scale`, isn't it?

Think about it this way: if your canvas is 1000 pixels wide, and you then call `scale(2)`, what coordinate will be in the upper-right corner? Since you've scaled by 2, the new coordinate will be 500, which is `1000 / 2`, or `width / scale`. Note that you have to keep track of the scale value yourself.

I'm pretty sure this pattern holds no matter what the width or scale is. I'd recommend putting together some example programs to test whether the point shows up where you expect it to. If not, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there.